# Converting &amp; to & in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a URL string in the following format.

```
http://myserver.com/_layouts/feed.aspx?xsl=4&amp;web=%2F&amp;page=dda3fd10-c776-4d69-8c55-2f1c74b343e2&amp;wp=476f174a-82df-4611-a3df-e13255d97533
```

I want to replace `&amp;` with `&` in the above URL. My result should be:

```
http://myserver.com/_layouts/feed.aspx?xsl=4&web=%2F&page=dda3fd10-c776-4d69-8c55-2f1c74b343e2&wp=476f174a-82df-4611-a3df-e13255d97533
```

Can someone post me the code to get this done?

**i changed the code like this. but not working**

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK))
{
            Log.v(TAG,"link link: "+property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().replace("&amp;","&"));
            message.setLink(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().replace("&amp;","&"));           
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
private String decode(String url)
{
   return url.replace("&amp;", "&");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Decode:**

```
Html.fromHtml((String) htmlCode).toString();
```

**Encode:**

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

[String.replace(target, replacement)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: still not working . the parsed node value i got is broken when &amp; occured.